# jquery-svg-pan-zoom library zooming

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

I'm using https://github.com/DanielHoffmann/jquery-svg-pan-zoom for panning and zooming in on generated SVG content.

The zoom works but it doesn't zoom where I point on the image, when I zoom in with mousebutton1 it focuses on the top and when I use the scroll it focuses on the bot of the image. In Daniel Hoffmans example you can choose wherever you want to zoom in with either button, anyone that had a similar problem with this library?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the image I was using was too big, hence the wierd zooming,changing size fixed it!

Comment: hi there, I am the author of the plugin can you email ( daniel.hoffmann.bernardes at gmail.com ) me the image you had problems with and the exact options you used that were giving problems? I only found out your question today, next time please feel free to open an issue on the github project.